Firebase State changing problems, Page does not change its aspect when user is logged in
Basically when the user is logged in I want the homepage to have written my account instead of login/register. I tried my chatpgt since I'm a beginner but it is not working. I would really appreciate a help. I have no idea how to solve it.
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.10.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script>
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.10.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.10.0/firebase-analytics.js";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.10.0/firebase-auth.js";
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  const firebaseConfig = {
    I have removed my keys here
  };
  
  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const auth = firebase.auth();

  // Listen for auth state changes
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in, show "My Account" link
      document.querySelector('.navigation').innerHTML = `
        <a href="chat" class="nav-link">Chat</a>
        <a href="account" class="nav-link">My Account</a>
      `;
    } else {
      // No user is signed in, show "Login / Register" link
      document.querySelector('.navigation').innerHTML = `
        <a href="chat" class="nav-link">Chat</a>
        <a href="auth" class="nav-link">Login / Register</a>
      `;
    }
  });
</script>

Here is the nav bar in the html:
<header>
        <div class="header-container">
            <div class="logo-container">
                <h1 class="site-title">Athena</h1>
            </div>
            <nav class="navigation">
                <a href="chat" class="nav-link">Chat</a>
                <a href="auth" class="nav-link">Login / Register</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>


At first glance the code to handle onAuthStateChanged looks fine, but "it isn't working" is really hard to help with. Is there any error message? If not, did you already debug the code on your machine? If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?
